# Flutter set ThemeData background to LinearGradient

Tags: flutter, colors, themes

Is there a way to set the `backgroundColor` of `ThemeData` class to a LinearGradient? My app will be changing between different themes and I want that each theme to have a different gradient. I tried setting the LinearGradient to backgroundColor but gave me a `The argument type 'LinearGradient' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'.` error.

this is what I tried

```
final _darkTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
    primaryColor: Colors.black,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
//    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF212121),
    backgroundColor: const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.green]),
    accentColor: Colors.white,
    floatingActionButtonTheme:
        FloatingActionButtonThemeData(foregroundColor: Colors.black),
    dividerColor: Colors.black12,
);
```

Any suggestions? I do not want to set each container manually or have an extra constants class to somehow associate with each theme.

Comment: I think your best bet is to just settle for the constants class. Is there any reason in particular you don't want to use one?

Comment: I would rather just use a property of an already existing class rather than doing extra work. Now I need to figure out how to select constants based on selected theme. Also, extra code might increase possibility for bugs.

Comment: @BadrB Maybe there is a way to extend ThemeData? If I could add additional properties to ThemeData for 2 colors, then I could use those colors like:
gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Theme.of(context).color1, Theme.of(context).color2]).

Whenever the theme would change, then those values would change accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I could achieve this by defining *primary* color and *secondary* color in the *colorScheme* of a custom theme class.

```
class AppTheme {
  AppTheme._();

  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    accentColor: Colors.purple[300],
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
      primary: Colors.green,
      secondary: Colors.green[100],
    ),
  );

  static final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    accentColor: Colors.purple[300],
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
      primary: Colors.green[800],
      secondary: Colors.green[600],
    ),
  );
}
```

In the custom button widget, I will set primary as gradient start color and secondary as gradient end color, like this:

```dart
child: RaisedButton(
  elevation: 8.0,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  child: Ink(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          ],
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
    child: Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        title,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

Finally, this is what I got:

[image: light mode on iPhone]

[image: dark mode on Android]

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best and efficient way to do it, but a very simple solution which works. I created two variable within my theme class `MyThemes`. Based on the selected theme those two variables, `gradientColorA` and `gradientColorB`, will change accordingly. I simply call those variables through the constructor - `TriviaThemes.gradientColorA`.

This is my theme class:

```
class MyThemes {
    static Color gradientColorA = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
    static Color gradientColorB = Color(0xFF000000);

    ThemeData getTheme(String themeName) {
      if (themeName == 'darkTheme') {
        gradientColorA = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
        gradientColorB = Color(0xFF000000);
        return _darkTheme;
      } else if (themeName == 'lightTheme') {
        gradientColorA = Color(0xFF000000);
        gradientColorB = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
        return _lightTheme;
      } else {
      return _lightTheme;
    }
  }

  final _darkTheme = ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
    primaryColor: Colors.black,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    accentColor: Colors.white,
    floatingActionButtonTheme:
        FloatingActionButtonThemeData(foregroundColor: Colors.black),
    dividerColor: Colors.black12,
  );

  final _lightTheme = ThemeData(
    accentColor: Colors.black,
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE5E5E5),
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    buttonColor: Colors.blue,
    dividerColor: Colors.white54,
    disabledColor: Colors.grey,
    floatingActionButtonTheme:
        FloatingActionButtonThemeData(foregroundColor: Colors.white),
    fontFamily: 'Simplifica',
    primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
  );
}
```

This is how the gradient code looks:

```
gradient: LinearGradient(
  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  colors: [
    TriviaThemes.gradientColorA,
    TriviaThemes.gradientColorB,
  ],
),
```